# The days visited and days consecutive is missing from my Area 51 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

That's it basically.

Is this by design?

Comment: Yes. Or old code base.

Comment: @Ladybug - good point, I'm not *that* bothered (but it would be nice to know if I'm anywhere near Enthusiast), but it is an anomaly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've fallen a bit behind in pulling in changes from the main sites.  We'll get there eventually.

**EDIT**

Aaand a year and half later, Area 51 profiles now show total & consecutive days visited.

Comment: That's OK. It's just that it's an anomaly.

Comment: Is this still being worked on?

Comment: @Ambo100 Yup! I just edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It *was* there originally. When the "consecutive days" feature was introduced, it was shown on Area 51 as well. It was retracted at some point from only Area 51, which indicates to me that they chose to remove it specifically from that site. [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), Reason:Unknown